# How does constructor conversion work in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, implicit-conversion

How does constructor conversion work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace::std;

class One {
public:
    One() { cout<<"One"<<endl;}
};

class Two {
public:
    Two(const One&) {cout<<"Two(const One&)"<<endl;}
};

void f(Two) {cout<<"f(Two)"<<endl;}

int main() {
    One one;
    f(one); 
}
```

produces the output

```
One
Two(const One&)
f(Two)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any constructor that can be called with a single argument is considered an `implicit conversion constructor`. This includes simple 1-argument cases, and usage of default arguments.

This conversion is considered in any context that wants X and provided Y, and Y has such implicit conversion possibility.  Note that a plenty of other, built-in conversions also play as a mix (like adjusting const-ness, integral and fp promotions, conversions, etc.)  The rule is that at most one "user defined" implicit conversion is allowed in the mix.

In some cases it may be quite surprising, so the general advice is to make any such ctors `explicit`. That keyword makes the conversion possible but not implicitly: you must use T() syntax to force it.

As an example consider `std::vector` that has a ctor taking size_t, setting the initial size. It is explicit -- otherwise your `foo(vector<double> const& )` function could be mistakenly called with foo(42).

Answer (score 0):

It's right result. Since `constructor` is not `explicit` - implicit conversion works (here `One` is implicitly converted to `Two`).

`one` is created, then when passed to `f` converted to `Two`.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler has to create copy of `Two` instance on stack. When you call `f()` with argument which is object of class `One` (or any other) compiler looks to definition of class `Two` and tries to find constructor which takes `One`(or any other) object(or reference) as an argument. When such constructor has been found it constructs object using it. It's called implicit because compiler do it without your interference.

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int number) {cout<<"Foo(int number)"<<endl;}
};

void f(Foo) {cout<<"f(Foo)"<<endl;}

int main() {
    f(24); 
} ///:~
```

Output will be:
Foo(int number)
f(Foo)

Answer (score 0):

What the `Two(const One&) {cout<<"Two(const One&)"<<endl;}` constructor means is that you're allowed to construct a `Two` value at any time - implicitly - from a `One`.  When you call `f(one)` it wants a `Two` parameter, it's given a `One`, so the compiler puts 2 and 2 together and says "I'll make a temporary `Two` from the `One` and complete the call to `f()`"... everyone will be happy.  Hurray!